# form input value through ID, not name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with an input that has a name an id.

When I try to get the value of the input by using `document.getElementById`, I get an error.

I can access the element by using the form name and the input name, but it makes the script a lot less flexible.

Any workarounds?

Here's the code I have:

```
<form name='myform'>
   <input name='n1' id='i1' value='stuff'>
</form>

<script>
   var s=document.getElementById("i1").value;
   alert(s);
</script>
```

I have the script in an external .js file and I want to make sure that if someone changes the name of the form, the script still works.

Comment: What is the error? I tried your code on jsFiddle and it worked fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/m6AEx/

Comment: What kind of error do you get? That code snippet ought to work fine.

Comment: Is the js file included before the form?

Comment: I feel silly. It does seem to work here when I simplified it to the barebones, but it doesn't work in my actual script...

Comment: The error I get in the actual example is TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: The actual code that generates an error is at http://worldcitiesdatabase.info/test1/

You need to select the continent to get the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code works just fine, look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vvs9d/)

Just make sure that you call the script after the DOM is ready. Also make sure that there are no other elements with the same `id`.

Comment: The actual code that generates an error is at http://worldcitiesdatabase.info/test1/

You need to select the continent to get the error.

Comment: You do not have id on those elements.. `selectedCountry`, `selectedCountryName`, `selectedRegionName` ... are only as `name` atrtibutes..

Comment: GRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR. What a dumbass I am... Thank you

Assumptions are my worst enemy. Sometimes, I am so sure that the code is there that I won't see it even if I look straight at it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if supported

```
function getElement (id)
{
   if (document.getElementById)
   {
      return document.getElementById(id);
   }
   else if (document.all)
   {
      return window.document.all[id];
   }
   else if (document.layers)
   {
      return window.document.layers[id];
   }
}
```

Comment: I really do not think that browsers that do not support `document.getElementById` are still in circulation .. See compatibility at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: It's the Internet, anything is possible.